# Replace the word 'blank' into a textbox

Tags: twig

is there any way where I can able to replace the word 'blank' into a textbox using Twig?

example: blank you blank a good time?
output would be: __________ you __________ a good time?

Comment: What do you mean with inside a textbox? Twig comes with the filter `replace`, e.g. `<input type="text" value="{{ value | replace({'blank' : '', }) }}" />`

Comment: like this one @DarkBee
http://jsbin.com/riwedekomu/edit?html,output

Comment: `{% set t %}
      <input type="text" name="test">
 {% endset %}
 <strong>{{ q.title | replace({'blank': t, 'Blank': t}) | raw}}</strong>`

I have this code so far and it worked. the only problem is the textbox goes to the next line. I'm using bootstrap css

Comment: here is the output ---> http://imgur.com/a/jTDjf

Comment: Should open a new topic about that bootstrap layout problem then if your input problem is solved